# Scala isn't allowing me to execute a batch file whose path contains spaces.Same Java code does.What gives?

Tags: scala, process, runtime

Here's the code I have:

```
var commandsBuffer = List[String]()
commandsBuffer ::= "cmd.exe"
commandsBuffer ::= "/c"
commandsBuffer ::= '"'+vcVarsAll.getAbsolutePath+'"'
commandsBuffer ::= "&&"
otherCommands.foreach(c => commandsBuffer ::= c)
val asArray = commandsBuffer.reverse.toArray
val processOutput = processutils.Proc.executeCommand(asArray,true)
return processOutput
```

`otherCommands` is an `Array[String]`, containing the following elements:

- `vcbuild`
- `/rebuild`
- path to a .sln file

vcVarsAll contains the path to Visual Studio's `vcvarsall.bat`. It's path is `C:\tools\microsoft visual studio 2005\vc\vcvarsall.bat`. The error I receive is:
`'c:\Tools\Microsoft' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`.

The `processutils.Proc.executeCommand` has the following implementation:

```
def executeCommand(params:Array[String],display:Boolean):(String,String) = {
  val process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.exec(params) 
  val outStream = process.getInputStream
  val errStream = process.getErrorStream
  ...
}
```

The same code, executed from Java/Groovy works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried all the combinations I could think of. What finally worked was omitting `cmd.exe /c` from the combo.